# Automate transfer of csv file to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, bash, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a csv file that I will be regularly updating through a batch script that calls cygwin+ bash script. **I would like to automate the upload of the csv file into a MySQL database such that a table in my database would be updated with the csv file at regular intervals**. The database is currently running on a Windows Server 2003 machine and administered with phpMyAdmin.

I have looked online and found some ways that I could achieve part of that, but I am confused as to where the code presented in those sources should be placed and how they would be called. For instance, [Import CSV file directly into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143938/import-csv-file-directly-into-mysql) seems to show how to upload a csv file to a MySQL database from the SQL command line once, but not repeatedly, the latter being what I need.

I would prefer the solution to involved bash scripting (as opposed to batch and php) if possible (i.e. **I would prefer a solution that I could integrate with the bash scripts that update the csv file**).

Thank you

Comment: If Java environment is installed on your machine. DBIS can be useful. You don't need to write code or batch. Just create project and configure. https://dbisweb.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute a MySQL script from the command line by doing something like:

```
mysql -uUsername -pPassword database_name < infile.sql
```

You could invoke that from the command line and in the infile.sql you could have code like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' TO table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Comment: quick comment, TO needs to be INTO TABLE

Answer (score 0):

You can use a here document:

```
# some bash script stuff
mysql ... <<EOF
SQL COMMANDS
GO HERE
EOF
# more bash script stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Quartz to create a cronjob - for periodically updating your database. with the help of cronmaker (http://www.cronmaker.com/), you get to choose when and how often your database gets updated.

This is a sample SQL Script to import data into your MySQL database:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/.../filename.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

run the above script in your cronjob using your preferred  language.