# load excel files into mysql automatically

Tags: mysql, database, excel, csv

I would like to know what would be the best way to automate the loading of an excel file into a mysql database.

The file would most likely be .csv, although, if there is a solution for text files, i can live with that. The data in to file would have to replace what is already in the database table.

I am searching for a solution meanwhile, and have found several for doing approximately this manually, as in, loading a file once, but i need this to happen every few minutes, if it is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate transfer of csv file to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314271/automate-transfer-of-csv-file-to-mysql) or [Import CSV file directly into MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143938/import-csv-file-directly-into-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

There is a native MySQL feature that allows importing a CSV file easily: [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html). All you need to do is declare your field- and line-separator correctly, if the default settings do not match your input file.

Please note that a CSV file is not an Excel file. It is a file format that Excel happens to be able to read.

If you really want to import Excel files (a `.xlsx`  file, taht is), then you need some external library to first parse the Excel file, as MySQL is not able to read it natively.