# Upload CSv Data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import CSV file directly into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143938/import-csv-file-directly-into-mysql)

I am totally new in php as i need to send some data from csv to database.

Comment: I am using this code. Please check it why its not working

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example code on the [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) documentation. Basically inside that loop, instead of echoing out the data, you could insert it in a mysql table.