# CSV to mysql loading

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I'm trying to upload this csv file to mysql on my hosting.

The csv is built by two columns:

```
alias, id
```

and than each row contains the data.

Here is an image

[image: a screenshot of my csv file]

But the mysql rejects me.
why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import CSV file directly into MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143938/import-csv-file-directly-into-mysql)

Comment: How or what does MySQL reject? And is this actually a csv file, or an Excel file?

Comment: If you are trying to upload a csv file then you have to select the CSV format in the import section. Either mention what kind of tool you are using with version or let us know what it's reject (Error code)..

Comment: csv do not have columns. Either you show up the excel sheet, or you didn't export it as csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also open up csv from excel and generate series of insert statements.  Not the best solution but might be useful if you're looking for something quick and dirty.

Answer (score 3):

Create a table "test_table " with two fields "alias" and "id", then execute this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.csv'
INTO TABLE test_table
IGNORE 1 LINES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(alias, id);
```

if your are using phpMyAdmin use the import option of phpMyAdmin. Choose CSV file format

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution using PHP

```
$file = 'path/to.csv'; 

$lines = file($file);
$firstLine = $lines[0];
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    if($line_num==0) { continue; } //escape the header column
    $arr = explode(",",$line);
    $column1= $arr[0];
    $column2= $arr[1];
       
    echo $column1.$column2."<br />";
        //put the mysql insert statement here
}
```