# Import a CSV file into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv

I'm trying to import CSV data into a MySQL database using the `fgetcsv` function.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
     $var = 'Invalid File';
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

     if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv") {
         $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
         $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vpireport");
     $rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
     if($rows>=0) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM vpireport") or die(mysql_error());

        for($i =1;($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE; $i++) {
            if($i==1)
            continue;
            $sql = "INSERT into vpireport
                                    (item_code,
                                     company_id,
                                     purchase,
                                     purchase_value) 
                                     values
                                    (".$data[0].",
                                     ".$data[1].",
                                     ".$data[2].",
                                     ".$data[3].")";
            //echo "$sql";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }

     fclose($handle);
    ?>
     <script language="javascript">
     alert("Successfully Imported!");
     </script>
     <?
 }
```

The problem is it gets stuck in between the import process and displays the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'S',0,0)' at line 1

The file is imported only partially each time. Only between 200-300 lines out of a 10000 line file are imported.

Here is the DDL of my table:

```
create table vpireport (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    item_code int,
    company_id int,
    purchase double,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(company_id) references users(userid)
);
```

I haven't been able to find the problem so far, any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i think it is not able to segregate comma separated values from data. can u post a sample data field?

Comment: can u please show your table definition(DDL) ? posibly $data wwas not properly escaped.\

Comment: It looks like you have  a `'` in one of your fields.  You should always use mysql_real_escape_string on strings that you interpolate into queries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143938/import-csv-file-directly-into-mysql you can use load data infile as answered by pekka in above question. load data infile syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: hey Neal i think this link may help to you it had clear explanation......http://blog.lysender.com/2009/04/importing-huge-csv-file-via-php/

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to escape quotes, which you could accomplish using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and [prepared statements](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

I've skipped most of your code in the example for brevity and just focused on the `for` loop.

```
<?php

    // Use PDO to connect to the DB
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=YOUR_DB;host=localhost';
    $user = 'DB_USERNAME';
    $password = 'DB_PASSWORD';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    for($i =1;($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE; $i++) {
        // The query uses placeholders for data
        $sql = "INSERT INTO vpireport
                    (item_code,company_id,purchase,purchase_value) 
                VALUES
                    (:item_code,:company_id,:purchase,:purchase_value)";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        // The data is bound to the placeholders
        $sth->bindParam(':item_code', $data[0]);
        $sth->bindParam(':company_id', $data[1]);
        $sth->bindParam(':purchase', $data[2]);
        $sth->bindParam(':purhcase_value', $data[3]);

        // The row is actually inserted here
        $sth->execute();
        $sth->closeCursor();
    }
```

That won't get rid of any problem characters, though, so you may want to look at some kind of data sanitization if that poses a problem.

Answer (score 1):

uncomment the //echo "$sql"; and look what is the last query (with error) - it may be that the csv data contains strange characters or the query is cut off.

BTW: you can also import csv file by mysql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = 1;

if (($handle = fopen("albums.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',','"')) !== FALSE) {
            if($row!=1){    
                $num = count($data);
                $albumIndex=0;

                //Insert into tbl_albums 

                $sqlAlbums="INSERT INTO tbl_albums(albumName) VALUES ('".$data[$albumIndex]."')";
                $resultAlbums=mysql_query($sqlAlbums);



                }
            }
            $row++;

            }
        }
fclose($handle);
```